# Getting Segmentation Fault: 11, on get_string

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying out `get_string` from the CS50 library. The `get_string` function, seems to cause a Segmentation Fault error. Do you have any advice?

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    string answer = get_string("What's your name? ");
    printf("Hello, %s", answer);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code can give segmentation fault

Comment: @EugeneSh. this is the terminal output: Macbook-Pro:Clang MACBOOK$ make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
Macbook-Pro:Clang MACBOOK$ ./hello
Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Yes it can, string (which is `char*`) can be NULL, Documentation recommends checking for that specifically https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/

Comment: @JackWhite Found in the docs *"Returns the read line as a string. If user inputs only a line ending, returns "", not NULL. Returns NULL upon error or no input whatsoever (i.e., just EOF)."*. Sounds an unlikely case, unless the OP intentionally feeding it with EOF...I still think the OP is not really running *this* code.

Comment: Goaarrrnnn... edit in the get_string() code..

Comment: Well that can cause a segfault alright. I think it's worth checking for that first. Op may be running the code incorrectly, such as without checking option "Run in terminal" in IDE settings which may cause `stdin` to be `/dev/null`. They may  have not realized this yet because very first line of the code causes segfault.

Comment: @JackWhite i'm running it from the terminal, as you can see on the 2nd comment of the post.

Comment: It is just about possible that a simple program is unable to allocate any memory, and `get_string()` returns `NULL`. OP can test if that is the case.

Comment: That was just an example. Please check if it returned `NULL` and if so - let's try to find out why. Step-by-step in debugger to see if crash happens before or after `get_string()` and if it returns `NULL` (don't rely on debugger when crash already occured).

Comment: @JackWhite How can i test it out?

Comment: `if(answer == NULL) printf("NULL value"); else ...`

Comment: Please replace the whole code with `printf("Hello, world!");`, compile, run, see it is printing the message. Then replace the code back, compile and run again. And tell us if it is still segfaulting.

Comment: I would step in the debugger. If you do not have a debugger or do not know how to use it, try at least to insert `printf("%d", (int)answer); if ( 0 == answer) { return 1; } ` after `get_string` and before your `printf`. (this is a hack, ignore compiler warnings).

Comment: @WeatherVane still getting the same error, not printing out anything :(

Comment: @EugeneSh. the hello world code works, and it prints, but the other one with the get_string gives me the error.

Comment: @JackWhite this is the new code: ```string answer = get_string("What's your name? ");
    printf("%d", (int)answer); if ( 0 == answer) { return 1; }
    printf(answer);``` still getting the error

Comment: Is `printf(answer);` what's actually in your code? You should never do that. What is the string you enter? Have you copy/pasted the *exact* code into the question?

Comment: Doesn't matter, if `printf("%d", (int)answer);` didn't execute (and it should not cause segfault by itself) then `get_string()` itself caused segfault. In that case there is probably something wrong with the library. Please post your `makefile`

Comment: From the command line posted above I don't see any linking with the cs50 library. But that should result in link time error, not in segfault. Have you messed with the cs50 files by a chance?

Comment: @EugeneSh. no i haven't.

Comment: It's probably somewhere in the `makefile`. Please post contents of your `makefile`

Comment: @JackWhite where can i find the ```makefile```?

Comment: Should be in the same directory you run `make` in

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's not there, all i can find there are the hello.c file and another hello executable file, nothing else

Comment: Ok so you are using implicit make rules, but how does it even compile then? You need to include `-lcs50` parameter when compiling (you probably also need to specify path to the library files, for example something like this: `export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` assuming that is where cs50 was installed) But the issue here is that it should have not compiled in the first place, instead giving you a link error

Comment: @JackWhite okay so i've added the ```export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib``` to my bash profile, and i'm compiling using the ```-lcs50``` parameter, but it's still giving the same segfault error

Comment: There is definitely something fishy going on and I'm not really sure what. Just to be sure, because I'm running out of options, did you compile cs50 library on the same computer or downloaded/copied the binaries from somewhere else? And if it's the latter, are you absolutely sure it is compatible with your architecture? i.e. you are not trying to compile against windows version on a mac, or 64-bit library on a 32-bit system...

Comment: @JackWhite [link](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/releases) this is the one that i've downloaded, i have no clue what could be wrong except the cs50 library install, because i'm sure that get_string is giving the segfault, because without get_string it works. The install is for mac and linux, as said on the github readme.

Comment: Ok something seems to be wrong with lib.I don't have any access to a mac to test. The only simple thing I can recommend is to try another version of the library. (you should first uninstall current version with `sudo make uninstall` from the same directory you installed it from). If that won't work the only thing possible here is building the library with debug information and debugging the library. I understand this lib is related to computer science class which means you are probably a student so are likely not comfortable digging that deeply? Can you ask your teachers for help or something?

Comment: I still don't get why someone would teach someone to use these kind of  functions. Would be a lot better if you were to create something similar yourself, and easier to debug.

Comment: What happens if you download the files from https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/tree/develop/src and then compile it directly into your program instead of using the library?  When I do that it works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/S12ftyvQu

Comment: The other thing you can try is, instead of `string answer = get_string("What's your name? "); printf("Hello, %s", answer);` try `if (get_string("What's your name? ")) puts("Not NULL"); else  puts("NULL");` and see what it says.

Comment: Ooookay, Mac OS X apparently has built-in symbol named `get_string`. I posted a kludge as an answer, if someone has a better idea - please post it.

Comment: Actually, I suggest you ask another question, something like "How do I override symbol `get_string` defined on Mac OS X with one in a library" with tags like: `ld` `macos` `c` `linker` and such. And also I found this: https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some digging I think I found the culprit. And it's apparently not where we looked.

Mac OS X apparently has built-in symbol named `get_string`, this is why it compiled without the library and why it keeps crashing.

There may be several approaches to this problem

#### Compile `cs50.c` into your binary

This method was mentioned [here](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/55). I have not tested it but it reportedly works.

Compile your code like this:

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 hello.c ../../../github.com/cs50/lib50-c/src/cs50.c -o hello
```

where `../../../github.com/cs50/lib50-c/src/cs50.c` is the path to file `cs50.c` that is in subdirectory `src` of `cs50` library source code - if it's different on your computer please use the correct path.

You could also just copy the `cs50.c` file to the directory with `hello.c` and just specify `cs50.c` without path

Please note that you must specify this file ***after*** yours or it won't work!

Actually, this should be enough in that case:

```
cc hello.c cs50.c -std=c99 -o hello
```

You will need to include `cs50.c` ***after*** yours every time you compile your code from now on.

#### Rename the function

Since I don't have a Mac, I cannot test anything so will list the one way that will work for sure - rename the function `get_string` to `get_string2`. It's not a good solution, but it's all I can give you right now.

Please only use this if the first approach does not work.

1. go to the directory from which you installed cs50
2. uninstall it by issuing command `sudo make uninstall`
3. open file `cs50.h` from subdirectory `src` in any text editor
4. search and replace all occurrences of  `get_string` with `get_string2` (I had one on line 108 and two on line 109)
5. save and close the file
6. open file `cs50.c` from subdirectory `src` in any text editor
7. search and replace all occurrences of  `get_string` with `get_string2` (there are a lot of them)
8. save and close the file
9. return to original cs50 build directory and run commands:

```
make clean
make 
sudo make install
```

10. go to directory with `hello.c`
11. edit `hello.c` and replace `get_string` with `get_string2`
12. compile with `cc hello.c -lcs50 -o hello` and run with `./hello`

You may also need to issue following commands before compilation and execution:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

13. From now on you will need to change each use of `get_string` in your code to `get_string2`
14. don't forget to change back when submitting your code.

Alternatively you could put something like this at the beginning of your programs:

```
#ifndef get_string2
#define get_string2 get_string
#endif
```

...this means that for everyone else running your code (and have no macro `get_string2`) this will define `get_string2` to be the same as `get_string` - so your code will work with both modified and unmodified library.

---

Again, this is clearly not the best way to do that, but since I cannot test it, this is the best that I could think of. Sorry.

If someone else suggests a better way - that would be great

Comment: `-std=c99` should prevent any non-standard symbols being defined - if this really is the problem it should be reported as a compiler bug